Pre-radio navigation/positioning on a ringworld
I'm working on a ringworld, built by a sufficiently advanced society but currently inhabited by significantly less advanced societies; certainly pre-electricity. I'm trying to figure out navigation; I'm figuring spinward/anti-spinward can be done with a sextant referenced off points on the far side of the ring, but I can't figure a way to accurately measure distance to the edges.

Does this ringworld have sunshades or otherwise experience night on its sunward side?

Does it have a central hub.... and spokes?

Is this a Niven ring or a Banks orbital?

@MontyWild Can you see what happens to comments on a question? I left what I thought was a pretty good comment that hinted at some solutions but didn't have time to make it an answer. It's gone.

@JBH Deleted by L. Dutch... probably as an answer in comments.

How wide is your ringworld? Are we talking millions of kilometers, hundreds, or thousands? Is the top of the wall readily visible? How tall are the walls compared to the width of the ring?

Math
The sextant measures the angle between the horizon and a celestial body, though here it works fine for markings. You might think this doesn't work on a ring world, but in essence it is just curved the orher way. Because you can get the sextant level with the griund you can measure the angle to the marking.
You should know how big the ring is. From there it becomes a math problem. If you have a certain angle towards a marking you can calculate the distance towards it. On a ringworld everything is fixed. If it's 180° it's a flat 2000km. At 90° it is 1414,2km long, or arc distance 1570,8km. Do not worry if you use imperial. You can just replace the km with miles and it works out. You can make an easy table to look up for the less math inclined, as many people in that era probably can't read and write much.
It becomes a calculation of your angle compared to the circle. You can calculate both the distance as the spaceship flies or the distance along the arc. With a single marking you can be on two spots on this ring. If you add a second you'll know exactly where you are, as you should know the order of the markings.
Calculations:
Straight distance(d) is calculated by d = root(radius²+radius²-2radius²cos(angle)). In the example it would be:
√(1,000^(2)+1,000^(2)−((2×1,000^(2))×cos(90))) = 1,414.2
And for 91°:
√(1,000^(2)+1,000^(2)−((2×1,000^(2))×cos(91))) = 1,426.5
To get arc distance we first need circumference (C). C=2 * pi * radius. In our example:
2000 is diameter. Radius is 1000. 2 * pi * 1000=6283.2km
If we want to know the distance we can use the degrees on the sextant as a measurement of percentage of the circle. At 90° that is 90/360=0,25, or 25%. So you take 25% of 6283,2. 1570,8.
It massively simplifies the calculations when you're in a circle. You can just plug in your radius, an angle and you should be fine. Make the calculations in excel or something of you do them often, so you only need to change the angle. I did assume an observer of 0 height for ease. The people can have some smart people make the sextant with a fixed height in mind, with the degree markings correct for the expected angles.

Use the sun
On the sunward side of your ring-world if you stand directly in the middle of the ring equidistant from both sides, the sun should be directly above at a perfect 90 degree angle. Because the ring cross section is flat, when you move closer to the edges, the angle of the sun will change.
A precise sun dial that has been previously calibrated could then give you your position relative to the edges. How much change in the shadow depends on the cross section length of your ring world and the distance to the sun. After that, you just solve a right triangle problem.
Even if your characters don't have the distance to the sun or a Pythagoras around, this will still work. You just need to sail to the edge of the world and mark the sun dial. It will be accurate forever.

I would like some extra information of this answer. 1) I think you mean 90° compared with the horizon. Technically it is 180° above you. 2) depending on the distance of the sun to the ringworld the light can hit near parallel. Shadows do not perceptibly change size if you go higher. On Earth it only changes thanks to the curvature of the Earth. So unless the light source is a whole lot closer a sundial would only work for spinward/anti-spinward if there's a day and night cycle. The question asked. Knowing your time is knowing your place compared to visible landmarks in parts of the day.

@Trioxidane I am assuming that the ring world is built around the main star. As if you took a slice out of a dyson sphere. IFF that slice is flat, this would work. In contrast, if we are talking about a halo type construct orbiting the star, then it would not. OP did not specify, so I assumed the former.

Distance to the edges
First, I'm assuming your ring world has walls. This is a good assumption because the force caused by the rotation such that a person standing on the inside of the ring would feel (e.g.) 1G "gravity" would cause anything not affixed to the ground to eventually slough off the edges. Larry Niven dealt with this in his ring world stories.
Besides, I need the walls.
The perceived width of an object some distance away is...
$$W = d'\frac{W'}{d}$$
Where...

W' is the actual width of the observed object.
"d" is the distance from you to the object.
"d'" is the reference distance used to declare the actual width.

Think of it this way.
You're some distance away from two massive parallel lines drawn on the "southern" (by declaration) wall. You hold up a ruler and the measured width between the two lines is 0.1 meter. You happen to know that the actual width of the lines is 10 meters when observed from a distance of 100 meters from the wall.  Therefore...
$$d = 100*\frac{10}{0.1} = 10km $$
This could be arbitrarily simplified by giving up a bit of precision by declaring any width (W') between the two lines on the wall when observed from a unit distance (one meter). Let's say the distance between the two walls is 10,000 km (we're using Larry-esque dimensions here). You know you're at the exact middle because the measurement of the two widths is equal at one centimeter. What must the distance between the lines be to allow this measurement?
$$W = \frac{W'}{d}$$
$$0.01 = \frac{W'}{5,000,000}$$
$$W' = 50 km$$
Given the distances involved, 50km is not an unreasonable number. But it would be easy enough to create a pattern that allowed for more precise measurements the closer you are to the wall. For instance (click to expand):

The image is not horizontally to scale. I took the liberty to be artistic. Who knows (OK, you do) how your alien builders would express this? But I have three layers of distance precision, signified by the horizontal flags off each triangle. The widest and tallest measure is 50 km wide, inner-edge to inner-edge, and has three flags top and bottom. The second (two flags) is 20 km wide. The third (one flag) is 5 km wide. The decorative interiors of the inner two measures are meant to help obscure them when measuring at distances relating the the third (three flags).
Only if you're perpendicular
I can imagine measures like this periodically along the walls. I can also imagine a numbering system (oh, let's say 0-359) that indicates either the distance from zero in (e.g.) kilometers, or the number of degrees one is along the circumference of the ring. (This cool idea isn't shown in the image above).
But this really only works well if the observer is exactly perpendicular to the symbols. What if one isn't? The odd circle on the left has that as its purpose. The lines are 45° apart. As a person walks parallel to the wall, the perception of the angle changes, narrowing until it's perceived to be 0°. Knowing the angle really is 45°, a little trigonometry allows the observer to know how far off perpendicular they are, and therefore how much to de-skew the perceived width of the symbols.
I'll leave that formula as an exercise for the reader. Hint: read @Trixodane's answer.
Frankly, a symbol set like this can be quite complex. As shown, it allows a "reasonably" precise measure of how far from the wall one is. But additional symbols can be added (like the serialization mentioned above indicating where along the ring the present symbol is) to mark the location of all kinds of things. Like medical centers, important resources or bureaucratic structures, really anything... just in case all the technology that most certainly would be present fails and one is found hiking the unfathomably long distances one would discover on a ring world.
That last point can't be stressed enough
In a way, what you've asked for is a bit silly. Cool! But silly. A ring world of any appreciable size would be so honking huge that the need for visually locating oneself on the surface is flat out ridiculous. No one could march even an appreciable fraction of the distance around the ring in their lifetime.
While technically a ring world could be any distance from a star, prudent engineering would build it to take most advantage of the star's energy and habitability. That means the ring circles the star in the star's goldilocks zone. Here at Sol, that's the orbit of Earth... meaning the ring's circumference is approximately 940 million kilometers.
Million... million... has a nice ring to it.
A round average walking speed for an adult is about 5 km/h. Walking the circumference of the ring without stopping for sleep, eating, toiletries... etc. would take 21,461 years, two months and a bit over a week.
So the wall symbols aren't for land-based observations. At best, they're for airborne observations if equipment failed. But even your average passenger jet would require 126+ years to fly around the ring. And considering the technology required to build the ring in the first place, the idea that the builders would expect anyone to need markers like this gets pretty incredulous pretty quickly.
So, while I've offered you a solution to your problem... I recommend you use it judiciously.
In 1971, after Larry Niven had published his first Ringworld novel, MIT students at the World Science Fiction Convention roamed the halls chanting, "The Ringworld is Unstable!" They loved the idea of what he'd done so much they took the time to determine whether or not it could be real... and discovered that mathematically, it was unstable. Larry fixed the problem in his next book by adding Bussard Ramjets that were used to periodically give the ring a boost to keep it on course.
You won't have that luxury. What people will prove is that the symbols wouldn't be useful to anyone given the enormous size of the world. Whatever use they could be would only be useful in a region so small that the next set of useful symbols would have to actually overprint the first.
People finding themselves alone with only a compass and two sticks to rub together for fire will spend the rest of their lives enjoying the beauty of nature. Until the tiger shows up.
So, think through what you're trying to achieve... because the sheer size of the object you're working with makes using manual sightings like this a bit... trite....
Are there any alternatives?
Yup. Today (in the U.S. and I'm sure in many countries around the world) you can easily buy a laser distance measurement tool — right off the proverbial shelf. You'll want one a bit more on the industrial scale, but the fact that we can buy this trivially (for less than $100 USD!) strongly suggests that nobody with the technology to visit this ring world would arrive without one. Especially if you write it into your story as standard geological survey equipment for all "X" class ships.
It broke when you crash landed? Well... tigers....
